# Getting the active url of browser in C# windows form application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, firefox

I have created a window form application.
This App get the active url of browser and save this into the text file.
And this works fine in **chrome** & **IE**.

But when i use **firefox**, this will not work. This code fails to get the active url of **firefox** browser.

I don't know why this happening.

I am using the following code to find the URL

```
 public string GetBrowsedUrl()
        {

            IntPtr hwnd = APIFuncs.getforegroundWindow();
            Int32 pid = APIFuncs.GetWindowProcessID(hwnd);
            Process process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
            string appId = proc.Id.ToString();
            string appName = proc.ProcessName;
            string appltitle = APIFuncs.ActiveApplTitle().Trim().Replace("\0", "");
            if (process == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("process");

            if (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                return null;

            AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
            if (element == null)
                return null;

            AutomationElement edit = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));


            string result = ((ValuePattern)edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value as string;
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** are you trying to do this?

Comment: You cannot use this code for firefox because both have different architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i found the answer

```
public string GetBrowsedUrl(Process process)
{
    if (process.ProcessName == "firefox")
    {
        if (process == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("process");

        if (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            return null;

        AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
        if (element == null)
            return null;

        AutomationElement doc = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Document));
        if (doc == null)
            return null;

        return ((ValuePattern)doc.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value as string;
    }
    else
    {
        if (process == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("process");

        if (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            return null;

        AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
        if (element == null)
            return null;

        AutomationElement edit = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit));


        string result = ((ValuePattern)edit.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value as string;
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: For firefox it provides URL of the oldest open tab only and not the active tab, any thing else that could resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use this code for firefox too.

I recommend a third party library named NDde to do this very easily.
[Here is NDde link](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ndde)

```
    public string GetFirefoxUrl()
    {
        try
        {
            Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("Firefox");
            if (pname.Length != 0)
            {
                DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
                dde.Connect();
                string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
                url= url.Replace("\"", "").Replace("\0", "");
                dde.Disconnect();
                return url;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        catch
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code is giving an error "The client failed to request \"Firefox|WWW_GetWindowInfo!URL\"."